# Left outer join rails with eager loading on where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, left-join, eager-loading

I have got a system down issue while eager loading records with where condition.

I have read a blog on [link](https://mildlyinternet.com/code/includes-with-conditions.html). It spokes about the performance issue while using where condition with eager loading associations.

```
@customers = Customer.all.includes(:invoices, :receipts).where(invoices: { status: "open" })
```

"This generates two left outer joins. Whats going to happen is that the database is going to return a row for every unique combination of customer, invoice and receipt. So if we have 25 customers, each customer has 10 invoices (250 total) and 10 receipts (250 total). The result set that is returned is not 525 records, but something closer to 2500 records. Now Rails has to instantiate all of that into ActiveRecord objects."

I am not getting how come it generates 2500 records?

Answer (score 1):

If there are 25 customers, each with 10 invoices and 10 receipts, then using 'where' with 'includes' will generate an SQL query like this:

```
select ...
from customers 
left outer join invoices on invoices.customer_id = customers.id
left outer join receipts on receipts.customer_id = customers.id
where invoices.status = 'open'
```

Assuming all the invoices are open, this query will return 2500 rows because the left outer join query will create all possible combinations of the customers, invoices and receipts tables, which is 25 x 10 x 10.  This is how left outer joins work.

ActiveRecord will then take those 2500 rows, merge them all together, and create considerably less active record objects.

In the resulting active record objects, each record will only exist once. For example, there are only 10 items in this @customers array:

```
@customers = Customer.all.includes(:invoices, :receipts).where(invoices: { status: "open" })
```

Also, each invoice and receipt will only exist as a single record rather than be duplicated many times like it is in the rows returned by the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does output of the first left outer join will be the input of second left outer join?

Comment: Do I deserve an up-tick? :-)